# search in nsmutablearray and add to another...?

Tags: iphone, search, nsmutablearray

Im stuck in weird situation. 'weird' in sense, it loose performance of my iPhone app.
My situation is like I have an nsmutablearray with below type of data

```
(
    {
    Line1 = "Ashish";
    Line2 = "Gujarat";
    Line3 = "AAA";
    Line4 = "AAA";
    Line5 = "AAA";
    LineCount = 5;
},
    {
    Line1 = "George";
    Line2 = "IL";
    Line3 = "GGG";
    Line4 = "GGG";
    Line5 = 1;
    LineCount = 20;
}
)
```

It's only two records, actually my array have thousands of it.
Now I want to add the block in another nsmutablearray when any of the line have the search value.
example if my search condition is **a** then array two have the first record, and array will be

```
(
    {
    Line1 = "Ashish";
    Line2 = "Gujarat";
    Line3 = "AAA";
    Line4 = "AAA";
    Line5 = "AAA";
    LineCount = 5;
}
)
```

LineCount is dynamic, ie if it is 10 then Line1....Line10 will be there in each record.
And search must be within Line1...LineN and not in LineCount field.
ex. if search condition is **5**, it will not return me anything.

Comment: NSMutableArray can only contain objects. You did not post any objects, so how are we supposed to help?

Comment: So, above whole can consider as object there.

Answer (score 0):

Use [NSPredicate_Class](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSPredicate_Class/Reference/NSPredicate.html) to sort

The NSPredicate class is used to define logical conditions used to constrain a search either for a fetch or for in-memory filtering.

See a good example [here](http://www.wannabegeek.com/?p=149)

Comment: I try with NSPredicate `NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains[cd] %@", searchText]; NSArray *results = [membersMArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate]; [membersMFilterArray addObjectsFromArray:results];` but it not find anything.